# Vue 3 Composition API - How to get the component element ($el) on which the component is mounted?

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api, vuejs3

I want to use `onMounted` to initiate a third-party library. To do that I need the component element as its context. In Vue 2 I would get it with `this.$el` but not sure how to do it with composition functions. `setup` has two arguments and none of them contains the element.

```
setup(props, context) {
    onMounted(() => {
        interact($el)
            .resizable();
    })
}
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

In Vue 3, components are no longer limited to only 1 root element. Implicitly, this means you no longer have an `$el`.

You have to use `ref` to interact with any element in your template:

```
<div ref="root" />
```

In the `setup` function, you should instantiate `root` as `const root = ref(null)`.

In the Options API, you can just use `this.$refs.root` in any method or hook, as long as it's after `mounted()`.

As pointed out by @AndrewSee in the comments, when using a render function (not a template), you can specify the desired `ref` in `createElement` options:

```
render: function (createElement) {
  return createElement('div', { ref: 'root' })
}
// or, in short form:
render: h => h('div', { ref: 'root' })
```

---

**initial answer:**

As outlined in [docs](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/api.html#template-refs),

> [...] the concepts of *reactive refs* and *template refs* are unified in Vue 3.

And you also have an example on how to `ref` a "root" element. Obviously, you don't need to name it root. Name it `$el`, if you prefer. However, doing so doesn't mean it will be available as `this.$el`, but as `this.$refs.$el`.

```html
<template>
  <div ref="root"></div>
</template>

<script>
  import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

  export default {
    setup() {
      const root = ref(null)

      onMounted(() => {
        // the DOM element will be assigned to the ref after initial render
        console.log(root.value) // this is your $el
      })

      return {
        root
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

In Vue 3 you're no longer limited to only one root element in `<template>`, so you have to specifically `ref`erence any element you want to interact with.

---

Update, 2 years later.
Specific syntaxes for various component styles (they are not different solutions, they are different ways of writing the same thing):

**`<script setup>`**:

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
const root = ref(null);
onMounted(() => console.log(root.value.outerHTML));
</script>
<template>
  <div ref="root" />
</template>
```

**`<script setup lang="ts">`**:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
const root = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null);
onMounted(() => console.log(root.value?.outerHTML));
</script>
<template>
  <div ref="root" />
</template>
```

**Options API**:

```html
<script>
  export default {
    mounted() {
      console.log(this.$refs.root.outerHTML);
    }
  }
</script>
<template>
  <div ref="root" />
</template>
```

Comment: Why is it not :ref="root" as when you use other variables? ref="root" looks like a simple string.

Comment: @curly, `ref` is already binding, just like `v-on` and `v-bind` are. Ultimately, the only person who can answer your question is Evan You, the creator of Vue.

Comment: While this solution may work, roland's answer using <script setup> with ref(null) is by far the most concise -- doesn't require explicit return, and yields the best compilation results. I'm always wary of messing with the render function in Vue. :)

Comment: @jtalarico, first of all, `<script setup>` syntax was still RFC 2 years ago, when I answered. Second of all, regardless of the syntactic sugar you coat it in `<script setup>`, `defineComponent()`, `export default {}` or OptionsAPI, the gist of the answer remains the same: template refs are the recommended way of targeting any element in `<template>`, including the root element. I've added `<script setup>` and `Options API` syntaxes, for users who do not know how to translate from one to the other.

Comment: I don't disagree - just commenting for anyone new hitting this article and might have  trouble deciding which way to go. BTW, there was a bug in the template ref implementation in Vue 3 that would cause it not to work on v-for elements. In Vue 2/options api, it results in an array. In Vue3/comp api, it results in a null reference. I believe a fix is in the works as of yesterday.

Answer (score 7):

Just adding my 2 cents here, and wanted to correct what some other answers are saying that Vue 3 does not have `$el` anymore.

**It does still have it**: https://vuejs.org/api/component-instance.html#el.

**Its use is discouraged** in case of multi-root where the `$el` element can't be decided to a specific root element, and **for consistency** with single-root components (where $el works the same way as Vue 2), the documentation suggests that you use $refs instead.

For multi-root components, the `$el` ref is on a the closest text node before the elements (or comment for SSR hydration).

**It does not mean that `$el` is unreliable, au contraire, since this mechanism is used internally and for SSR hydration.**

**In most cases, you can use `$refs` and you should.**

But if you can't, like in the case below, you can still rely on `$el`:

```html
<template>
  # an empty text node exists here in the DOM.
  <slot name="activator" :on="activatorEventHandlers">
  <other-component />
</template>
```

In this case (case of tooltips and context menus where an event listener is attached to a user slot), the first element is a slot, and you can't add a ref on a slot.

So using `$el` will point to the first text node, so `this.$el.nextElementSibling` will be the element given through the user slot.

Comment: Would be useful to show how you get to `$el` in Vue 3

Answer (score 6):

#### In Vue 3 + Composition API there is no `$el` alternative provided.

Even if you use Vue 3 with Options API, due to the availability of Fragments, it is recommended to use template refs for direct access to DOM nodes instead of relying on `this.$el`.

---

#### How to initiate a third-part-library

Let's say we have a div element for the third-part-library:

```html
<template>
  Below we have a third-party-lib
  <div class="third-party-lib"></div>
</template>
```

And then we want to initiate it from the Javascript:

> #### Solution 1 (recommended): Using template refs

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

const $thirdPartyLib = ref(null); // template ref

onMounted(() => {
  $thirdPartyLib.value.innerText = 'Dynamically loaded';
});
</script>

<template>
  Below we have a third-party-lib
  <div ref="$thirdPartyLib" class="third-party-lib"></div>
</template>
```

> #### Solution 2 (not recommended): Using non-documented `@VnodeMounted`

```html
<script setup>
function initLib({ el }) {
  el.innerText = 'Dynamic content';
}
</script>

<template>
  Below we have a third-party-lib
  <div class="third-party-lib" @VnodeMounted="initLib"></div>
</template>
```

[See both solutions live](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-winifc?file=src/components/UsingRef.vue)

Comment: Could you please clarify what is `ref('')` in `const $thirdPartyLib = ref('');` and how to run your live solutions?

Comment: I'm also getting "Property 'innerText' does not exist on type 'string'" designtime error when I'm trying to repeat your Solution 1. It looks like `const $thirdPartyLib = ref('');` is a string init. Why should string has this property?

Comment: @Niksr the `ref('')` which now is `ref(null)` is a template ref. In order to run the live solutions, you can simply type `vite` in the terminal and then click Enter.

Comment: Got it. Many thanks! This solution, however, isn't that simple with the TS because of "Object is possibly null" error.

Comment: I found that just `ref()`  works best in all cases.