# Vue3 and Typescript error: Property '$el' does not exist on type 'void'. How to properly grab every tag type existing in DOM?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am in the process of converting a Vue2 project into Vue3 and Typscript. There are plenty of bizzare errors, but I am not sure how to handle this one on `$el`.

I am just looking to grab every `<g>` tag in the template above and I can, but this error persists.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image: Code sample with error]

Here is the template of the component, but the entire component is too big to put on stackoverflow. I need to target the `<g>` tag of.

```
<template>
  <div class="pep-header-decoration-light">
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="1158.942"
      height="143.376"
      viewBox="0 0 1158.942 143.376"
    >
      <g :style="`color: ${colors.green}`">
        <!-- ... -->
      </g>
      <!-- many more g elements to select here too -->
    </svg>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Suggesting as a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61600078/1426891), which talks about the deliberate lack of `$el`. Be careful about your use of `this`, too: Arrow functions don't get their own `this`, and the `this` in `setup` is `null` as listed [in the tip here](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#basic-usage).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue 3 Composition API - How to get the component element ($el) on which component is mounted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61600078/vue-3-composition-api-how-to-get-the-component-element-el-on-which-componen)

Comment: @JeffBowman Thank you for the answer. I did see the use of `ref` instead, but my template needs all <g> tags, which there are a lot of. Do I really need to go on every <g> tag and add a template ref? That seems a bit excessive

Comment: You didn't show us the template, if there's an SVG element you can set `ref` on that and do a `querySelectorAll` or other DOM traversal from there. You just can't rely on either `this` or `$el` specifically in your `setup`.

Comment: @JeffBowman I've added the template, but it's quite huge and I didn't think people needed to see it. So you mean putting the ref on the svg and then targetting from there? so something like this ?`$refs.$el.querySelectorAll('g')`

Thanks again for your help so far!

Comment: I've converted most of my feedback to an answer. I'll edit the less-relevant parts out of your question; in the future, please don't upload a screenshot of your code, but rather copy-paste the text so it's easier to read and modify. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in the question [Vue 3 Composition API - How to get the component element ($el) on which component is mounted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61600078/1426891), Vue 3 discourages the use of `$el`, since components can have more than one top-level element. Furthermore, [your arrow function won't redefine `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), and [`this` is not available in `setup`](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#basic-usage):

> `setup()` itself does not have access to the component instance - `this` will have a value of `null` inside `setup()`. You can access Composition-API-exposed values from Options API, but not the other way around.

Given that, you should probably define a `ref` for either your enclosing `div` or your enclosing `svg`, and use that to get to your element:

```html
<template>
  <div class="pep-header-decoration-light" ref="divEl">
    <svg [...]>
      <!-- ... -->
    </svg>
  </div>
</template>
```

Note that you'll need to return the new `ref` in the object that `setup` returns, and that [it needs the same name](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#accessing-the-refs) that it has in the template. You can access this later using `this.$refs.divEl`, but in the `setup` function you don't have access to `this` to get to `this.$refs`.

```
setup(props) {
  const divEl = ref<HTMLDivElement>(); // create the ref here
  onMounted(() => {
    // no `this` and no `$el`, so use `divEl.value`
    const shapes = divEl.value.querySelectorAll("svg > g");
    // ...
  });
  // ...
  return {divEl}; // exposes the ref named `divEl`, and since it matches
                  // the template, vue will populate it during mount
}
```

Comment: I don't find DivElement, the correct name should be Element or HTMLDivElement

Comment: That's right, was going from memory. Fixed.

Comment: Generally I completely agree. However, in my case [refs don't play nicely within loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71417860/9831274) (or at least not yet). Any suggestions for folks who need to type a Vue component to access $el?

Comment: @Ryan I'm not sure I understand your question. You can't get to `$el` from `setup` or the composition API directly, since the render function won't have been called yet. Outside of that [the first link in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71372032/1426891) has some alternatives, and if there are constraints beyond that you may need to specify them in your own question.

Comment: Apologies, that was confusing. Totally agree: no `$el`s in the composition API. However, `$el`s can be accessed via computed (or methods) defined in the composition API. All I'm really asking is how to type a Vue component so `someVueComponent.$el` doesn't throw a typescript error. Maybe it is worth writing up a separate question

Comment: @Ryan Ah, that helps, but has an unsatisfying answer: `$el` is only typed as a [Node in the docs](https://vuejs.org/api/component-instance.html#el) and an [Element in the declarations](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/ee57d9fd1d51abe245c6c37e6f8f2d45977b929e/types/vue.d.ts#L65), so there are no clever generics that will let you avoid normal means of [casting via `as` ("type assertions")](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or [narrowing (e.g. type predicates or `typeof` checks)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html).

Comment: @Jeff, thank you so much for your help! That brought a lot of clarity! I ended up [writing up a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73532500/how-to-type-an-arrow-function-parameter-in-a-vue-3-attribute-and-how-to-type-a-v) for a related issue and quoted you.