# How to type an arrow function parameter in a Vue 3 attribute and how to type a Vue component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, casting

We need to access element properties and are leveraging [Vue refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for) to do so. Unfortunately at this time [there is a known bug and ref arrays are not populated correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71417860/9831274) (thank you [@tony19](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6277151/tony19)!) Due to that we're using to [@tony19](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6277151/tony19)'s suggestion and adding the components to an array. Typescript does not like that the `el` parameter is not typed and the Vite project won't build because of it.
[image: Typescript arrow function parameter type error]

Below is a summarized version of the Vue file/component:

```html
<template>
  <some-component
    v-for="(someContent, index) in someContentArray" 
    :key="`${someContent.id}-${index}`" 
    :ref="el => contentComponents.push(el)"
  />
</template>
```

Also, we're using the [script setup tag](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html) in a [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) project.

```ts
import { ref } from 'vue'
// Components
import SomeComponent from './SomeComponent.vue'

// Props
const props = defineProps<{ someContentArray: SomeContentArrayType[] }>()

// Refs
const contentComponents = ref<any[]>([]) // Any ideas on how to type a vue component?

// Computed
const contentPositions = computed(() => {
  let positions: number[] = []

  contentComponents.value.forEach(ref => {
    const refBounds = ref.$el.getBoundingClientRect()
    positions.push(refBounds.top)
  })
  return positions
})
```

Also, also, is there a way to type a Vue component? The `el` above returns a Vue component and we just grab the `$el` property. I just used `any` to satisfy the `contentComponents` array typing.

I asked [@jeff-bowman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1426891/jeff-bowman) about typing the `$el` property and he gave [some great information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71372032/vue3-and-typescript-error-property-el-does-not-exist-on-type-void-how-to/71372654?noredirect=1#comment129804045_71372654). To summarize his answer: the `$el` property is typed as [Node](https://vuejs.org/api/component-instance.html#el) or [Element](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/ee57d9fd1d51abe245c6c37e6f8f2d45977b929e/types/vue.d.ts#L65) and is not easy to cast. (thank you [@jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1426891/jeff-bowman)!)

Comment: Does `:ref="(el: unknown) => contentComponents.push(el)"` fix the type issue?

Comment: Appreciate you're suggestion @StephenGilboy! Unfortunately no. I'm curious if typescript just "isn't allowed" within a Vue template.

Answer (score 0):

After writing this up and discussing it with a coworker we came to a solution.

We just migrated the inline/anonymous function to be a Vue method. The parameter was easily typed from there and Vue knows to pass `el` via the `ref` attribute.

```html
<template>
  <some-component
    v-for="(someContent, index) in someContentArray" 
    :key="`${someContent.id}-${index}`" 
    :ref="elementGrabber"
  />
</template>
```

```ts
import { ref } from 'vue'
// Components
import SomeComponent from './SomeComponent.vue'

// Props
const props = defineProps<{ someContentArray: SomeContentArrayType[] }>()

// Refs
const contentComponents = ref<any[]>([]) // Any ideas on how to type a vue component?

// Computed
const contentPositions = computed(() => {
  let positions: number[] = []

  contentComponents.value.forEach(ref => {
    const refBounds = ref.$el.getBoundingClientRect()
    positions.push(refBounds.top)
  })
  return positions
})

// Methods
function elementGrabber(el: any) {
  contentComponents.push(el)
}
```

Still haven't sorted out the best way to type a Vue component and am just using the `any` type above. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: The correct type is `ComponentPublicInstance`. `contentComponents.push` - ouch. It's unnnecessary for contentComponents to be a ref, would be easier to make it reactive array

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask! Agreed on making it a reactive array. Any better ideas on the `contentComponents.push`? I took that route based on [the bug mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71417860/9831274).

Comment: I believe this has been fixed some time ago https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for . Did you try it that way with up to date Vue?

Comment: The docs show it as working. I read through [this thread saying it still doesn't work](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/5525). Not sure which is more accurate. I think that's a good suggestion; I'll try updating Vue/Vite and see what happens.

Comment: Since the issue is closed, I'd expect this to be sorted out, while a workaround was a temp solution